# Swift - Using gesture recognizers on an image but not the view

Tags: swift, uikit, uigesturerecognizer

I have an UIImageView containing a single image. In storyboard I placed a pan gesture recognizer on the image view. It works, however, I can only reposition the entire UIImageView and not just the image. In the example below I want the red frame to remain the same, always. I only want to reposition the underlying image.

The code for my pinch gesture recognizer is obviously transforming the imageView which is the problem. But I don't see a way to attach the gesture recognizers to the image itself. Or if that's even what I should be trying to do...

```
@IBAction func scaleImage(_ sender: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
   imageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: sender.scale, y: sender.scale)
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're saying

> reposition the entire UIImageView and not just the image

it sounds like you think that there's some view container for image inside `UIImageView`.

But it's not true. `UIImageView` is already the lowest level you can get. There's a `layer` underneath, but it's bound to the view.

When you're changing transform of `UIImageView` this affects gestures calculation, that's the reason of your problems.

I suggest you wrapping `UIImageView` with `UIView` and adding gesture recognizer for this container view.

Also depending on your needs, the simplest solution may be placing image inside a `UIScrollView` and enabling zoom, this will allow user both to zoom and scroll through image.

Comment: I thought I could work with the image property of the image view so that only it would be altered. Kind of like contentMode seems to do based on its setting. But both of your solutions make sense so I will try that. Thanks!